# Can I use Netty to retrieve DNS TXT data? eg. using DnsNameResolver?

Tags: netty

It looks like I'm able to get DNS lookups, but I don't see anything in the answer.

```
final DnsNameResolver resolver = new 
DnsNameResolverBuilder(EVENT_LOOP_GROUP.next())
            .channelType(NioDatagramChannel.class)
            .queryTimeoutMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(dnsTimeoutSeconds).plusMillis(dnsTimeoutMilliseconds).toMillis())
            .recursionDesired(true)
            .build();
    try {
        final AddressedEnvelope<DnsResponse, InetSocketAddress> result =
                resolver
                        .query(new DefaultDnsQuestion(host, DnsRecordType.TXT))
                        .get();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use Netty to retrieve DNS TXT data? eg. using DnsNameResolver?

Yes you can.

What you did isn't wrong but some parts are missing. An `AddressedEnvelope` is container for a message, sender and recipient address. You only need to get the message from the `AddressedEnvelope` and then look for answers in the `DnsMessage`.

```
private static String resolveTxt(String dnsRecord) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    DnsMessage message = resolver.query(new DefaultDnsQuestion(dnsRecord, DnsRecordType.TXT)).get().content();
    if(message.count(DnsSection.ANSWER) > 0) {
        DefaultDnsRawRecord record = message.recordAt(DnsSection.ANSWER, 0);
        return DefaultDnsRecordDecoder.decodeName(record.content());
    }
    return null;
}
```